# Using ListPreference in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-preferences

I have a settings menu with a list preference from the sample settings activity in Android Studio.

```
 <ListPreference
    android:key="example_list"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages"
    android:defaultValue="5"
    android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null" />
```

In this list preference you can select 8 different things.

```
  <string name="pref_title_add_friends_to_messages">Klasse</string>
<string-array name="pref_example_list_titles">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_example_list_values">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to use the value of the preference to display links which belong to the 8 different settings.

E.g.:

5 - google.com

6 - wikipedia.com

etc.

As a beginner, how do I get the value of my preference and how do assign the values to the links and put them in one variable, which changes when the preference is being changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<string-array name="pref_example_list_values">` will be used as value in the `ListPreference`. To get the current value, use:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("example_list");
String currentValue = lp.getValue();
```

To get the value and display it in a text, have a `TextView` and set the text:

```
/* You might create 'if' statement for 8 times because of there are 8 different value in the ListPreference*/

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

if (currentValue.equals("5")) {
// do your thing here, i.e. google.com
tv.setText("Welcome, 5!");
}
if (currentValue.equals("6")) {
// do your thing here, i.e. wikipedia.com
tv.setText("Welcome, 6!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another question, is there a way to display the value in a text, for example: "Welcome, (value here)!"

Comment: There are some mistake in my answer, please check it again. To set the value in a `TextView`, you can do it one by one to every value. Oh, if this answer helps you, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When I try to insert the code, getValue is makred red and findPreference is showed as deprecated. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I don't know the reason why it showed as deprecated, but it still works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of your preference like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String value = sharedPref.getString("example_list", "default value");
```

I don't understand the rest of your question.  What does

> how do assign the values to the links and put them in one variable, which changes when the preference is being changed?
>   mean?

Also, I find [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) on preference settings very helpful.